# Finding erroneous records from batch insert data load with executemany() in cx_Oracle in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

Loading data to oracle via python 3 using cx_Oracle library. Here is  code snippet:

```
for fl in processing_list:
    fname = fl.split('/')[-1]
    data_set = []
    data_reader = csv.reader(open(fl,'r'),delimiter='|')
    for rec in data_reader:
        rec.insert(0,fname)
        data_set.append(rec)
    curs.executemany('insert into test_sdp_dump values(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19,:20,:21,:22,:23,:24,:25,:26,:27,:28,:29,:30,:31,:32,:33,:34,:35,:36,:37,:38,:39,:40,:41,:42,:43,:44,:45,:46,:47,:48,:49,:50,:51,:52,:53,:54,:55,:56,:57,:58,:59,:60,:61,:62,:63,:64,:65,:66,:67,:68,:69,:70,:71,:72,:73,:74,:75,:76,:77,:78,:79,:80,:81,:82,:83,:84,:85,:86,:87,:88,:89,:90,:91,:92,:93,:94,:95,:96,:97)',data_set,batcherrors=True)
    
    for error in curs.getbatcherrors():
        print('Error Message:' + error.message + 'Row Offset:' + str(error.offset))
        print(data_set[error.offset])
```

It works fine while inserting and giving error message.
However, I need to have the erroneous records and keep it in file.
Tried to find the record via Row Offset but it doesn't give the correct records.
How can I get the erroneous records?
Suggest a way forward kindly.

Comment: For future readers' reference, the cx_Oracle documentation on this is at [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a list(`err`), and append your error messages to this list, and create a new file in `w` mode in order to write the messages in it line by line such as below code :

```
curs.executemany('INSERT INTO test_sdp_dump VALUES(:1,:2,..)',data_set,batcherrors=True)
err = []    
for error in curs.getbatcherrors():
    print(data_set[error.offset])
    err.append('Error Message:' + error.message + ' - Row Offset:' + str(error.offset+1))

with open('err.txt','w') as f_out:
        for i in err:
                f_out.write(''.join(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: thanks but question was to get the erroneous record for which insertion has failed @barbaros

Comment: hi @Leon , you already managed that through `Row Offset`.

Comment: actually its not giving correct row... that is the problem...what row offset actually?

Comment: row offset values equal to line number - 1 exactly (as list indexes start from zero) . If you want this, I can replace `str(error.offset)` with  `str(error.offset+1)`  @Leon

Comment: Found the problem. error.offset is integer value. Thats why when records number is high than integer variable limit, value of  `error.offset`  is being reset  and giving wrong value @Barbaros

Comment: What version of cx_Oracle are you using? Version 8.0 fixed an overflow issue with row offset when it exceeded 65535.